# Kentor Auth - Single SignOn

Tags: asp.net-mvc, okta, kentor-authservices

I am using Kentor.AuthServices for single SignOn. Using Okta as the Identity provider, I received a certificate ie, okta.cert which I added under App_Start folder and provided the below line

```
var idpOkta = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(IssuerUrlSamlOkta),              
                              authServicesOktaOptions.SPOptions)
               {
                LoadMetadata = true,
                MetadataLocation = metadataSamlOkta,
                SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri(signOnUrlSamlOkta),

            };

      idpOkta.SigningKeys.AddConfiguredKey(new X509Certificate2(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/okta.cert")));

      authServicesOktaOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(idpOkta);
```

There is no error. But the Issue is If I provide any certificate this line is passing. How I will know that the SAML assertions are signing with this line of code. If I am providing an incorrect certificate name I am getting error, not found. But If I provide any valid certificate from App_Start other than okta certificate still this line is passing without any error. How I will make sure that all the SAML assertions are signed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please see our documentation on how to use Kentor services with Okta: http://developer.okta.com/blog/2016/03/22/use-kentor-authservices-with-okta/

As per the documentation: "In the  section, download the okta.cert X.509 certificate from the instructions page in the Okta app and put it in the App_Data folder of your web application. Then reference it accordingly (such as with fileName=”~/App_Data/okta.cert”) in the web.config file."